# android studio libraries build with ndk-build aren't updated on run

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio-2.0, ndk-build

I use android studio for my project because of the NDK support it now has, but i still use makefiles because there are still things I can't do by using gradle.

I compile my source c/cpp files with ndk-build in the terminal, but when I hit run afterwards in Android Studio the changes aren't packaged in the APK until I do 'Build' -> 'Rebuilt project' (it uses old .so files).

The compiled .so files are put into the jniLibs/${arch} folder.

Is there a way to force gradle to repackage my compiled so files or to force a 'Rebuilt project'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while i found out you can do the following to rebuild the apk every time you deploy the app.

go to 'preferences' -> 'Build, Execution, Deployment' -> 'Instant run'.

and just toggle all of the boxes to off.

It is not really that good of a solution since it takes quite a while to launch an app, but it works for now.